# I2C communications seems overloaded or blocked

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, i2c, nrf52

I am working on an Arduino project with a Controllino Maxi Automation, Adafruit Feather nRF52840 Express and multiple sensors and displays. The setup so far is that the Controllino is the i2c master. The Adafruit Feather is a i2c slave that takes data from the Controllino to send it via BLE and responds via i2c with data it receives from BLE.

So far everything worked really well, but now I started connecting my 7 pressure sensors and things got really weird. I was not able to find any of the sensors with an i2c-scanner while the feather was connected. When I remove the Feather everything gets found by the scanner with no problem.

From what I have seen, I would guess that the constant requests/responses between the Controllino and the Feather overload/crash the i2c bus, but I don't really know.

Currently I am requesting and responding every time the main loop runs with no delays.
Should it really be an overloading/too much communication issue, what would be good practice to fix this? Or maybe there is a different/better way to separate the Controllino <-> Feather Communication from the i2c bus?

Comment: First of all I would rather think about electrical properties of the bus (impedance). Try to choose lowest speed (100kHz), adjust pull up resistors so you have sharp signal which goes to the ground well, etc. When you have a lot of I²C devices is better to spread them among few I²C controllers (Personally I would simply switch to SPI).

Comment: Thanks, I quite like the idea of switching to SPI, but I can't get the SPI library to work on the Adafruit device... I have also tried the Adafruit BusIO library, but then I don't know how to configure it as a slave device. Do you have a good example for SPI on Adafruit?